# Minimal number of covering boxes for binary matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, compression, cover

I have a binary matrix n*m (0's and 1's). Problem is to cover all 1's with non-overlapping boxes whose elements are all 1.

Example:

```
1111
0110
0110
```

Box can be represent with coordinates and lengths in each coordinate `(x,y,lx,ly)`. This example is covered with 2 boxes `{ (0,0,1,4), (1,1,2,2) }`.

I'm looking how to find cover with minimal number of boxes.

Thanks

Comment: Are the boxes allowed to overlap?

Comment: @Jeff: For the specified problem, you wouldn't gain any benefit by overlapping.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701887/find-the-set-of-largest-contiguous-rectangles-to-cover-multiple-areas/4701966#4701966

Comment: @Jeff: no overlapping. I edited text.

Comment: @biziclop: it is same problem. Thank you.