# Filling a Polygon with Least Amount of Rectangles

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, computational-geometry

I'm trying to render polygons, but they can only be rendered using axis-aligned rectangles. So, I' looking for an algorithm that can basically fill in a polygon using the **least** possible amount of rectangles. If it helps reduce the amount, the rectangles are allowed to overlap each other.

I've already implemented [this fill algorithm](http://alienryderflex.com/polygon_fill/), which mostly suffices. The downfall is that it restricts rectangles to each pixel row. I ultimately want to reduce the amount of rectangles as much as possible.

Comment: I assume from the question that that the polygon is pixelated? a vector based polygon won't be able to be filled with any finite number of axis aligned rectangles except in special cases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pixel representation of polygon is same as rectilinear polygon and you can partition it quite fast. See answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701887/find-the-set-of-largest-contiguous-rectangles-to-cover-multiple-areas).

Answer (score 0):

Removing that restriction (that each rectangle have a height of one pixel) helps in some special cases when the polygon is made of big rectangles, but not at all in the general case.

How about this: use that algorithm, but extend each rectangle upward and downward as much as you can, and when all of the rectangles are in place, eliminate redundant ones.

There is still a little bit of room for improvement, in that the *order* in which you eliminate redundant rectangles might matter in some very rare cases, but honestly I don't think it's worth worrying about for a practical solution.

Comment: When I think about it, I could just treat the rows as a bunch of rectangles, and then apply methods suggested in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919298/algorithm-for-finding-the-fewest-rectangles-to-cover-a-set-of-rectangles).